# How to suppress a warning in clang++?

Tags: warnings, clang++

I compiled the following c++ program:

```
 int main() {  2==3;  }
```

with:

```
clang++-5.0 -std=c++17 -Wunused-comparison prog.cpp
```

and got the warning:

```
warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
2==3;
~^~~
```

... so, probably this is not the correct way to suppress a warning in CLANG.

In the [clang manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-command-line-flags), this part is a "TODO".

What is the correct command-line flag to disable a warning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the clang diagnostic that you get from:

```
$ cat main.cpp
int main()
{
    2==3;
    return 0;
}

$ clang++ -c main.cpp
main.cpp:3:6: warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
    2==3;
    ~^~~
1 warning generated.
```

the bracketed:

```
-Wunused-comparison
```

tells you that `-Wunused-comparison` is the enabled warning (in this case enabled by default) that was responsible for the diagnostic. So to suppress the diagnostic you explicitly disable that warning with the matching `-Wno-...` flag:

```
$ clang++ -c -Wno-unused-comparison main.cpp; echo Done
Done
```

The same applies for GCC.

In general, it is reckless to suppress warnings. One should rather enable them generously - `-Wall -Wextra [-pedantic]` - and then fix offending code.

Answer (score 1):

add no warning flag as : -Wno-xxx :

> https://releases.llvm.org/12.0.0/tools/clang/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#diagnostic-flags

e.g.
enable the c++17 extension warning:

> -Wc++17-extensions

suppress the c++17 extension warning:

> -Wno-c++17-extensions